# Why does my Randomized SVD implementation use so much memory?

Tags: performance, julia

I have a Julia implementation (below) of randomized SVD from this paper, [Finding structure with randomness: Probabilistic algorithms for constructing approximate matrix decompositions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061). See the algorithm on page 9 if you're curious.

I would expect randomized SVD to be more efficient than SVD for large datasets, but it's slightly slower and uses *way* more memory. Here are my performance statistics from `@time`:

```
 SVD:  16.331761 seconds (17 allocations: 763.184 MiB, 0.82% gc time)
 RSVD: 17.009699 seconds (38 allocations: 1.074 GiB, 0.83% gc time)
```

Note that my randomized SVD uses over 1 GB of memory. I'm not sure why. Here is my implementation:

```
using Distributions
using LinearAlgebra

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function find_Q(A, l)
    #=
    Given an m × n matrix A, and an integer l, compute an m × l orthonormal
    matrix Q whose range approximates the range of A.
    =#
    m, n = size(A)
    Ω = rand(Normal(), n, l)
    Y = A * Ω
    Q, R = qr(Y)
    return Q
end

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function randomized_SVD(A, k)
    #=
    Given an m × n matrix A, a target number k of singular vectors, and an
    exponent q (say q = 1 or q = 2), this procedure computes an approximate
    rank-2k factorization UΣVt, where U and V are orthonormal and Σ is
    nonnegative and diagonal.
    =#
    Q = find_Q(A, 2*k)
    B = Q' * A
    S, Σ, Vt = svd(B)
    U = Q * S
    return U, Σ, Vt
end

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

m = 2000
n = 20000
k = 10
# Construct low-rank matrix
A = rand(m, k) * rand(k, n)
println("Rank of A: ", rank(A))
println("Size of A: ", size(A))

println("Throwaway test:")
@time svd(A)
@time randomized_SVD(A, k)
println("Actual test:")
@time svd(A)
@time randomized_SVD(A, k)

println("Completed")
```

Note that I call `@time` twice per the [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html), which says:

> On the first call (@time sum_global()) the function gets compiled. (If you've not yet used @time in this session, it will also compile functions needed for timing.) You should not take the results of this run seriously.

Comment: I have not checked the whole algorithm but it seems that `Q` is not a `m` x `l` matrix (you probably need to select its first `l` columns only).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, that was it. I ended up using `LAPACK.geqrf!(Y)` to solve this issue. Feel free to answer the question if you want credit.

Answer (score 3):

As an additional note: the Julia documentation does not recommend using the @time macro for benchmarking. Better of using @benchmark macro from the BenchmarkTools.jl package

Comment: If you have a note, please leave a comment instead.

Comment: I'd love to but that action required a higher reputation